# <div><span><div> inside a container <div>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place two divs inside the container div. I want the `<div><span><div>` to be placed in the middle of the container `<div>` but I am having a hard time with the CSS.

This is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/59b3tdur/  (CSS included here)

```
<div class="DualScorepoints">
   <div class="LEFT">
        <span id="SCORE1" title="VP PPS">
          <a href="javascript:void()" style="color:#FFC90E; text-decoration:none; overflow:hidden" >100%</a>
          </span>
    </div>

     <span id ="Divider"> | </span>

   <div class="RIGHT">
      <span id="SCORE2" title ="DOM PPS">
          <a href="javascript:void()" style="color:#FFC90E; text-decoration:none; overflow:hidden" >80%</a>
       </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Also, what are you trying to place in the container, your explanation just says, "I am trying to place a inside a container". What does this mean? You should update it.

Comment: "I am trying to place two divs inside the container div." You've succeeded. You say you're having CSS issues. What is the visual result you hope to achieve?

Comment: @Hello let me know if this is somewhat the layout you are looking to achieve. I have significantly reduced its complexity, and removed the need for a random image to be used. It can be done all with css. https://jsfiddle.net/89noxcct/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to approach it.

```css
.theContainer {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #006699;
}

span {
  color: #FFD700;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#divider {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<font face="Source Sans Pro">

<div class="theContainer" align="center">
  <div class="left">
    <span> Left </span>
  </div>
  <span id="divider"> | </span>
  <div class="right">
    <span> Right </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` on `.DualScorepoints` for a quick solution, see https://jsfiddle.net/hyafgvo2/1/

This distributes the child elements evenly across the screen and makes a lot of other settings superfluous BTW (note that I erased a lot of CSS).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? flexbox is simple a way to solve that. If you want it on the left or right of the screen you could make it justify-content:left;
 https://jsfiddle.net/59b3tdur/9/

```
 .scorePoints{
      display:flex;
      justify-content: center;
 }
 .DualScorepoints {
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
 }
```

with that said it would be better if that divider, wasnt content but created with css. Its good generally to keep styling and html separate, you could do this by giving one of the divs a left or right border of 1px
example

```
 .score1{
     border-right: 1px solid white;
 }
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/